# Call of explicitly instantiated template function through conversion operator

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors, conversion-operator, explicit-instantiation

Let us assume we have a function template which is implemented in the cpp file with help of explicit instantiation like this:

*function.h*

```
template<typename T> void function(T val);
```

*function.cpp*

```
#include "function.h"

template<typename T> void function(T val) { /* do something */ }

template void function<double>(double val);
```

We are now able to call the function in a main file that includes *function.h* like this:

```
double val = 1.0;

function(val);
```

Let us further assume we have a class which is implemented like this:

*data.h*

```
class Data
    {
    private:
        double mVal;

    public:
        Data(double val) { mVal = val; }

        operator double () { return mVal; }
    };
```

The following code results in the linker error LNK2019: unresolved external (Visual Studio 2010):

```
Data a(1.0);

function(a);
```

We could use one of the following expressions to supply *a* to *function()*

```
function<double>(a);
function(double(a));
...
```

but why is it not possible to just call *function(a)*? Does there exist any other solution to achieve that without explicitly instantiating *function()* with type Data?

Comment: So you want the meaning of your program to depend on how much of your program you've already written? If some other TU later instantiates `function<Data>`, you want that to magically affect overload resolution in the already compiled TUs?

Comment: That is a good point indeed. I didn't think of the possibility to instantiate function() out of function.cpp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why is it not possible to just call `function(a)`?

It is. You're calling it. But remember that `function` is declared as:

```
template<typename T> void function(T val);
```

so template deduction will deduce `function<Data>`. The template deduction doesn't know that elsewhere in the code you only have a definition for `function<double>` - it just does deduction. And `function<Data>` doesn't have a definition, so it fails to link.

Performing the explicit cast yourself (either `function<double>(a)` or `function(static_cast<double>(a))`) would be the best solution in my opinion. Explicit is nice. You could additionally write a separate function with all the overloads you actually support and just forward to the function template:

```
void fwd_function(double v) { function(v); }
void fwd_function(foo v) { function(v); }
void fwd_function(bar v) { function(v); }

fwd_function(a); // now we call function<double> because fwd_function(double )
                 // is the what we're actually calling
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to call `function(a)`, because then `T` will be of type `Data`, and not `double`, even though it has that conversion operator. And because you are not explicitly defining it in the `cpp` file, you get a linker error.

Here are some solutions you could use:

```
//Call operator double() explicitly 
function(a.operator double());

//Specify T
function<double>(a);

//Casting
function(static_cast<double>(a));
```